# Microcontroller, Touchscreen QVGA and a Web Client?

Tags: linux, embedded, som

I've been working on a little ATmega for a year now, and have a pretty nice GUI and eventing system. Except, after completing the wireless driver, I'm left wondering, is there another way?

I want to know if anyone has come across any device that has GPIO, uC, QVGA display and touchscreen, but importantly - can support a web client. The idea is, the I could have a small embedded web server serving itself a webpage that displays on the QVGA screen. External clients could connect via wireless, and view the same screen.

I've seen lots of web servers in embedded applications, but not web clients. So I though a small Linux embedded device, and try and load on some web client and drivers to the QVGA/touchscreen. I also saw these; http://www.netmf.com/gadgeteer/get-started.aspx - 'system on module' devices that use .NET. Not sure if you could put a web client on that easily.

Can I get some direction?

Comment: Seems to be a shipping question which makes it off-topic/not-constructive, but the big issue here is resource demands. A "full service" web browsers is a *big*, memory and processor intensive application. If you are willing to accept a simple browser there are many projects in various states of completion and/or abandonment. See e.g. dillo or look around for a *small* webkit browser that leaves out many of the optional bits.

Comment: Stack Overflow is the wrong place for this question, so I'll only comment.  [This](http://axiomtek.a2s.pl/en/got-3570t-p-7176.html) is an AMD Geode (x86) based QVGA panel PC, advertised as running WinCE, but will no doubt support Linux; no GPIO, but that can be added added via PC/104 expansion.  Other solutions available; I searched "QVGA panel PC".

Comment: The challenge is probably going to be getting both the display and the GPIO in the same affordable device.  You can get a dirt cheap Android tablet which takes care of the display, but GPIO will be tricky and will probably have to go by way of a helper micro.  Or you can get something like a Raspberry pi (on up through the beagle family, or some smaller x86 derivaties), and end up having to pay more to get a touchscreen display set up on it.  But fortunately, today, once you accept external ram, and that someone else will be producing the board, you aren't too constrained on memory/compute.